# Microsoft Outlook add like / dislike options in email content

Tags: outlook

Is it possible to add like / dislike options to email content in Outlook ?

Basically if a user clicks the like or dislike I must get a feedback about the same.

Comment: The challenge is not in adding the UI, but in deciding on what to do with the "likes". I was thinking about adding the "like" button to outlook to allow social network-like interactions within our organization. However, the problem becomes how to show the likes - and who gets to see them. For example, if you "like" a message sent to 10 people, it would make sense to notify them all. Your add-in could do it, but what about people who use mobile devices? There are also privacy concerns (how do you control who sees your likes?)

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple solutions for this.

1. [Custom Voting Buttons](http://www.brighthub.com/link/header.aspx?u=http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-polls-in-email-messages-and-review-the-results-HP010355562.aspx?CTT=1&p=25198&returnUrl=/computing/windows-platform/articles/25198.aspx) (*built in exchange-only feature*)
2. [Custom Task Pane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608622.aspx) (*appears docked next to message pane*)
3. [Ribbon UI Customization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee906585) (*add buttons with custom images/custom groupings*)
4. [Custom Form Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx) (*new page or modifying default page)*
5. Injecting [HTML Links/Images into Content Body](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) (*won't work for text-only bodies*)
6. [Context Menu Customizations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692172.aspx#OfficeOLExtendingUI_ContextMenuforaMailItem) (*menu/submenu capabilities*)

As for tracking the results - it really depends on which solution you use above which route you take. I would probably get feedback from the users using the system to determine which route they would prefer after reviewing these options.